# is there any way to get the unique word count from a csv file

Tags: linux, awk

I have a text file content as below

```
Notes1,Notes2,Id3,Id4
I'd like to play tennis with you some day with everyone,Mary enjoys cooking,id1234,5678
Some of my friends can speak English well and turkish well,She likes bananas,id3456,9898
```

Final output something like:

```
word, iterationcount,id3,id4,columnname
I'd , 1, id1234,5678,Notes1
like, 1, id1234,5678,Notes1
with, 2, id1234,5678,Notes1 .... 

some, 1, id3456,9898,Notes2
well, 2, id3456,9898,Notes2
```

for each word for column1 and same output seperately for column 2 and its count based on group by on Id3, Id4

I tried multiple ways like below

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=NF-1; i++) words[$1","$2][$i]+=1} END {for (i in words) {for (word in words[i]) {print word "," words[i][word]}}} ' file.csv


awk -F, '{count[$2","$3]+=(NF-1); for (i=1; i<=NF-1; i++) words[$2","$3][$i]+=1} END {for (i in count) {for (word in words[i]) {print i, word, words[i][word]}}} ' file.csv | sort
```

Missing something , can any one pls suggest.

Comment: uff, *that* is a fragile format. How does it represent a `Note1` that reads `I like 1. making pancakes, 2. going on hikes and 3. arson on an industrial scale`? Note that there's a comma in the string.

Comment: @MarcusMüller we can modify the delimeter to something "&" or "$" , we can request vendor to modify it ,is there any way to achieve

Comment: that's no good, because if you change the delimiter to anything else, you then can't use that in the string. You usually want 1. something that is not CSV if you have freetext fields, 2. if it *has* to be CSV (it doesn't), quoted strings with well-defined quoting and quote escaping, all in a well-defined encoding (typically, UTF-8). But then, your `awk` lexer becomes dauntingly complex. Instead of `awk`, use a tool that can actually parse your data format. For CSV (again, I wouldn't use that at all for free-text data), that might be `Python`, or `mlr` (miller).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Current linux server doesnt have python or mlr and need to request admin. Is there a way to get in linux atleast similar output pls

Comment: yes, ask your admin. You need to parse data, so you need parser tools. Building something broken now only means more work for the admin when you're not around and things break. By the way, it's a bit unusual that a modern Linux server has `awk` but not `Python` these days; any redhatoid ships python (due to packaging depending on it), so do cloud-specific distros (e.g. amazon linux 2023). But you might be on something older, or debianoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk (which you're apparently already using given the code you posted in your question and is frequently the awk variant on Linux) for `FPAT` and arrays of arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    FPAT = "([^" OFS "]*)|(\"([^\"]|\"\")*\")"
}
NR == 1 {
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        fldName[i] = $i
    }
    next
}
{
    analyze(1)
    analyze(2)
}

function analyze(fldNr,     words,i,word,cnt,key,out) {
    out = "out" fldNr
    split($fldNr,words)
    for ( i in words ) {
        word = words[i]
        cnt[$3 OFS $4 OFS fldName[fldNr]][word]++
    }
    if ( !doneHdr[fldNr]++ ) {
        print "word", "iterationcount", "id3", "id4", "columnname" > out
    }
    for ( key in cnt ) {
        for ( word in cnt[key] ) {
            print word, cnt[key][word], key > out
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file.csv
```

```
$ head -100 out?
==> out1 <==
word,iterationcount,id3,id4,columnname
some,1,id1234,5678,Notes1
you,1,id1234,5678,Notes1
with,2,id1234,5678,Notes1
day,1,id1234,5678,Notes1
everyone,1,id1234,5678,Notes1
tennis,1,id1234,5678,Notes1
to,1,id1234,5678,Notes1
play,1,id1234,5678,Notes1
I'd,1,id1234,5678,Notes1
like,1,id1234,5678,Notes1
can,1,id3456,9898,Notes1
friends,1,id3456,9898,Notes1
well,2,id3456,9898,Notes1
Some,1,id3456,9898,Notes1
of,1,id3456,9898,Notes1
and,1,id3456,9898,Notes1
speak,1,id3456,9898,Notes1
my,1,id3456,9898,Notes1
turkish,1,id3456,9898,Notes1
English,1,id3456,9898,Notes1

==> out2 <==
word,iterationcount,id3,id4,columnname
cooking,1,id1234,5678,Notes2
Mary,1,id1234,5678,Notes2
enjoys,1,id1234,5678,Notes2
likes,1,id3456,9898,Notes2
bananas,1,id3456,9898,Notes2
She,1,id3456,9898,Notes2
```

The above assumes that if any of your fields include commas then they'll be wrapped in double quotes and if any of your quoted fields include double quotes they'll be escaped by doubling, per [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

It also assumes that none of your fields can contain a newline. If any of them can then see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for what you need to do to handle them.